# Is there any way to fetch documents with pagination using the Cassandra Node.js driver's built-in mapper?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax-node-driver

Is there any way to fetch documents with pagination using the driver's built-in mapper? The `findAll()` method accepts `pageState` as an option but does not return it to use it in next calls.

```
const result = await this.repository.findAll({ limit: 1 }, { fetchSize: 1 });

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

returns this JSON:

```
{
  "_rs": {
    "info": {
      "queriedHost": "127.0.0.1:9042",
      "triedHosts": {
        "127.0.0.1:9042": null
      },
      "speculativeExecutions": 0,
      "achievedConsistency": 10,
      "isSchemaInAgreement": true
    },
    "rows": [],
    "rowLength": 0,
    "columns": [
      {
        "name": "namespace_id",
        "type": {
          "code": 13,
          "type": null
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "archived_at",
        "type": {
          "code": 15,
          "type": null
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "channel_id",
        "type": {
          "code": 13,
          "type": null
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "created_at",
        "type": {
          "code": 11,
          "type": null
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "department_id",
        "type": {
          "code": 13,
          "type": null
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": {
          "code": 13,
          "type": null
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "identifier_type",
        "type": {
          "code": 13,
          "type": null
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "identifier_value",
        "type": {
          "code": 13,
          "type": null
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "last_assignee_id",
        "type": {
          "code": 9,
          "type": null
        }
      }
    ],
    "pageState": null
  },
  "_info": {
    "keyspace": "omnichannel",
    "tables": [
      {
        "name": "ticket_by_archive_time",
        "isView": false
      },
      {
        "name": "ticket_by_id",
        "isView": false
      },
      {
        "name": "ticket_by_identifier",
        "isView": false
      }
    ],
    "_mappings": {},
    "_columns": {},
    "_documentProperties": {}
  },
  "_isEmptyLwt": false,
  "length": 0,
  "pageState": null
}
```

Comment: Are you using the DataStax NodeJS driver?  Or are you connecting to StarGate?

Comment: @Aaron I'm using DataStax with a local cassandra node, the `pageState` also exists in `findAll` result when I stringify it but it's `null`

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code for invoking the `findAll` and processing the results?

Comment: @Aaron Done, I added the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was passing `limit` option, removing it and using only `fetchSize` fixed the issue.